# How to provide security for blob storage in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to provide access to blob storage in `Windows Azure` such that,only one domain can access the blobs in the `container`. I found there are Public, Private and Shared accesses to container. But they do not suit my requirement. In public we can access blob anytime from url. In private we can not access from url but can access from code if we provide storage account credentials. And in shared access we can access for some time as per the policies.

But I need like my website should access any blob from `blob-storage` that may be from either url or from code. But I should not access it from another browser by just pasting an url of blob. So unless and until I do not login in my application I should not be able to access blob storage url. Please let me know how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to make use of [`Shared Access Signature (SAS)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx) that are valid for very short duration (30 seconds or even less). As you know, SAS provide time-limited/permission-based access to your storage resources. So what you could do is keep your blob container's ACL `Private` instead of `Blob/Container`.

Assuming you're using .Net Client library and building an MVC application, what you would do in your controller is create a `SAS` on your container with `Read` permission which is valid for very short duration and pass that SAS token to your view. Then you would append that SAS token to the image URL in your view.

**Controller Code:**

```
        var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var container = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("container");
    var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        });
    ViewBag.SasToken = sas;
```

**View Code:**

```
<img src="https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/myimage.png@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SasToken)" />
```

Please note that this is not 100% foolproof because for the time SAS is valid, anybody can copy the URL and get the image but the issue can be mitigated by keeping the duration for which SAS is valid because once the SAS expires, even if somebody has the URL they will not be able to access the blob.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your reply. I got clue from your response and went ahead with new implementation as posted with another answer.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but instead of setting a SAS on a container, can you set it on an individual blob, so you can only access that blob and not other blobs in the same container?

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for this. I make container access level as **Private** and write **HTTP handler** in my application for retrieving blob files where I written logic like below in the ProcessRequest method.

**Handler**

```
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
        // Get the file name. 
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string blobContainerName = string.Empty;

           if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null)
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString["filename"] != null)
            {
                fileName = context.Request.QueryString["filename"];
            }

            if (context.Request.QueryString["source"] != null)
            {
                blobContainerName = context.Request.QueryString["source"];
            } 

            // Get the blob from blob storage.
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "FlexpathBlob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            // Read blob content to response.
            context.Response.Clear();
            try
            {
                blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
                context.Response.ContentType = blockBlob.Properties.ContentType;
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(context.Response.OutputStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

            context.Response.End();
        }
        else {
            context.Response.Write("You are not authorized to view this file.");
        }
    }
```

And access from the view like

**View**

```
<img id="imgVehicleImage1790" src="/Handlers/FileReciever.ashx?source=dealerinventory&amp;filename=1790_3b733b4e-b692-4650-95a6-855eb55145c4.png" style="border-width: 0px;width:208px;height:126px;">
```

This works fine for me. I can access all images and other blob files. and when I tried to access from the blob url it shows unauthorized access. Thanks!